# How is the same object returned multiple times in flyweight design pattern

Tags: java, flyweight-pattern

I have an example which demonstrates flyweight design pattern, where there are soldiers in a game. This soldier instance has to be used by multiple clients simultaneously. And [this](http://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern.html)link says the same object is returned if it is available in the map (or cache). Isn't this unsafe to use same object concurrently as a thread may change its property.

Comment: If soldiers are not thread-safe, then the design is broken.

Comment: Each solider is a `SoldierClient`.  The `SoldierClient` stores the modifiable state of each soldier - that isn't shared, so can be as thread-unsafe as it wants.  The only bit that **is** shared is the `SoldierImp`. This contains code for drawing a soldier, and routines for moving a soldier around. These should definitely be thread-safe and stateless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A flyweight pattern should only be used with immutable objects, regardless whether it is used in a single thread or in a multi-thread environment.